# Was Hazrat Fatima (May Allah Be Pleased With Her ) Present During The Mubahilah Event?

Tags: authenticity

According to Wikipedia, Husayn, Hassan, Ali, and Fatima (May Allah be Pleased With Them) were present when the Mubahilah event was happening. I wajnt to know what is the authenticity of the claim that these companions were indeed present during the Mubahilah event? According to some sources, only Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu) was present. **Can someone please tell me if Hazrat Fatimah (May Allah Be Pleased With Her) was also present during this event**? Jazakallah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event of Mubahila happened around 10 AH when the delegation came from Najran. Fatimah, Hassan and Hussain definitely existed at that point in time. And their presence is also evident by the verse itself:

> فقل تعالوا ندع أبناءنا وأبناءكم ونساءنا ونساءكم
>
> Say, "Come, let us call our sons and your sons, our women and your women ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:61](https://quran.com/3/61?translations=20)</sup>

As 'our sons' refers to Hasan and Hussain, the grandsons of the Prophet ﷺ; and 'our women' refers to Fatimah, the daughter of the Prophet ﷺ. And this has been noted by several exegetes.

It is also evident from the hadith:

> ولما نزلت هذه الآية: {فقل تعالوا ندع أبناءنا وأبناءكم} [آل عمران: 61] دعا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عليا وفاطمة وحسنا وحسينا فقال: اللهم هؤلاء أهلي
>
> When this verse was revealed - "Let us call our sons and your sons…" - the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) called 'Ali, Fatimah, Hasan and Husain and said: "O Allah, these are my family."
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2404d)</sup>